# SML - bidirectional infinite and finite sequence interleaving

Tags: sequence, sml, smlnj, sequences, seq

I have the next declarations of datatype and functions:

```
datatype direction = Back | Forward
datatype 'a bseq = bNil | bCons of 'a * (direction -> 'a bseq)

fun bHead (bCons (x, _)) = x
  | bHead bNil = raise EmptySeq

fun bForward(bCons(_, xf)) = xf Forward
  | bForward bNil = raise EmptySeq

fun bBack (bCons (_, xf)) = xf Back
  | bBack bNil = raise EmptySeq

fun intbseq k =
  let fun go Forward = intbseq (k+1)
        | go Back = intbseq (k-1)
  in bCons (k, go) end
```

The next function is written by me for interleaving two sequences like that:
if the first seq is `... ,1,2,3,4,5, .....` and the second is `...,5,6,7,8,9,...`
The new sequance of their interleaving is:

```
... ,3,-1,4,0,5,1,6,2,7,3, ......
```

Code:

```
fun binterleaving_aux _ bNil yq = yq
  | binterleaving_aux _ xq bNil = xq
  | binterleaving_aux firstb (bCons(x,xf)) (bCons(y,yf)) =
    bCons(x, fn dir => 
      if dir = Forward 
      then binterleaving_aux true (bCons (y, yf)) (xf dir)
      else if firstb 
           then binterleaving_aux false (yf dir) (xf dir)
           else binterleaving_aux false (bCons (y,yf)) (xf dir)));

fun binterleaving bseq1 bseq2 = binterleaving_aux true bseq1 bseq2;
```

And for that exmaple:

```
binterleaving (intbseq 5) (intbseq 1);
bForward(it);
bForward(it);
bForward(it);
bForward(it);
bBack(it);
bBack(it);
bBack(it);
bBack(it);
```

It is working great for 2 infinite sequences.

The problem is when at least one of them is finite.

For exmaple if I do:

```
binterleaving (bCons(10, fn dir => bCons((9, fn dir => bNil)))) (intbseq 5);
bForward(it);
bForward(it);
bForward(it);
bForward(it);
bBack(it);
bBack(it);
bBack(it);
bBack(it);
```

If I go back I lose the 10 and 9, and the opposite if firstly I went back, when I move forward I lose them ether.

The result is by the order of the calls:

```
val it = bCons (10,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (5,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (9,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (6,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (7,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (6,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (5,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (4,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (3,fn) : int bseq
```

And the correct result should be:

```
val it = bCons (10,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (5,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (9,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (6,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (7,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (6,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (9,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (5,fn) : int bseq
val it = bCons (10,fn) : int bseq
```

What are the changes in the code I should do, so that will be the behavior of the function?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is when at least one of them is finite.
>
> ```
> binterleaving (bCons(10, fn dir => bCons((9, fn dir => bNil)))) (intbseq 0)
> ```

When your finite sequence reduces to `bNil`, how is it supposed to get back to its original values? The semantics of interleaving a finite sequence with an infinite one seem a little under-defined.

That is, when the finite one ends and the infinite one continues, where is the reference stored along the infinite sequence at which point the finite one starts again in reverse?

Take the example above and evaluate it a few steps (forgive my lazy notation):

```
  binterleaving (bCons(10, fn dir => bCons((9, fn dir => bNil)))) (intbseq 0)
⇒ binterleaving (bCons(10, fn dir => bCons((9, fn dir => bNil))))
                (bCons( 0, fn dir => ...intbseq (+/- 1)...))
⇒ binterleaving_aux true (bCons(10, fn dir => bCons((9, fn dir => bNil))))
                         (bCons( 0, fn dir => ...intbseq (+/- 1)...))
⇒ bCons (9, fn dir =>
      if dir = Forward
      then binterleaving_aux true (bCons (0, fn dir => ...intbseq (+/- 1)...))
                                  ((fn dir => bNil) dir)
      else ...)
```

Evaluating this once by applying `Forward` to the outermost `fn` gives:

```
  bCons (9, (fn dir => ...) Forward)
⇒ bCons (9, binterleaving_aux true (bCons (0, fn dir => ...intbseq (+/- 1)...))
                                   ((fn dir => bNil) dir))
⇒ bCons (9, binterleaving_aux true (bCons (0, fn dir => ...intbseq (+/- 1)...)) bNil)
⇒ bCons (9, bCons (0, fn dir => ...intbseq (+/- 1)...))
```

At this point, there is no trace of the finite sequence 9 in any function capable of going backward. Only in the initial return value of `binterleaving`.

The fix mainly lies in the base case of `binterleaving` which throws away the finite sequence. Rather, the result of interleaving an empty sequence with a non-empty sequence should be a non-empty sequence that, when reversed, returns whatever the empty sequence was *before* it got empty (which was possibly also empty, but possibly non-empty).

You can see your bidirectional sequence as a lazy [zipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)) on lists. The book Learn You a Haskell has a [chapter on tree zippers](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers) that might be worth a read. In this chapter's terminology, you might want a function that returns a "breadcrumb trail". List zippers are conceptually a bit simpler, but sprinkled with the laziness of *'a bseq*s, syntactically not so.